# Subclass of a subclass of unittest.TestCase, with a different setUpClass classmethod

Tags: python, class, selenium, python-unittest

I currently have a subclass of unittest.TestCase which I use to run my selenium tests:

```
class FunctionalTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(1)

    @classmethod    
    def tearDownClass(self):
        self.browser.close()

    def method1(self):
        #some code here

    def method2(self):
        #some code here
```

I would like to subclass this class (FunctionalTest), where I would like to change the setUpClass method to disable javascript for the firefox browser, but still be able to use all the other methods of FunctionalTest :

```
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.set_preference("javascript.enabled", False);
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)              
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(1)
```

Subclassing like the following is not working:

```
FunctionalTestNoJS(FunctionalTest):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.set_preference("javascript.enabled", False);
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)              
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(1)
```

Any ideas on how to effectively go about this?

Comment: Define 'not working' in this case?

Comment: Overriding the class method just works *normally*, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#setupclass-and-teardownclass

Comment: Try removing @classmethod? and isn't the method just supposed to be named setUp()?

Comment: @d_rez90: no, it is a class method and it is run once per `TestCase` class.

Comment: Actually, a recent upgrade of Firefox is the source of my broken Selenium tests; I though the new test was not working b/c I was subclassing incorrectly.

Comment: Have you considered multiple inheritance with the actual tests being factored out to a separate class not inheriting TestCase? That way it isn't picked up automatically by the unittest framework as it would be if you used a simple Y-shaped hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I'm not sure of the reason for having @classmethod, but here ya go..

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime


class FunctionalTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(1)
        self.browser.maximize_window()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_method1(self):
        self.browser.get("http://javatester.org/javascript.html")
        now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S-%f')
        self.browser.get_screenshot_as_file('%s_%s.png' % (self.__class__.__name__, now))


class FunctionalTestNoJS(FunctionalTest):
    def setUp(self):
        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.set_preference("javascript.enabled", False);
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)              
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(1)
        self.browser.maximize_window()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Actually, a recent upgrade of Firefox is the source of my broken Selenium tests; I though the new test was not working b/c I was subclassing incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I was looking for something similar. It resolved my problem as well